# Script to find all .h file and put in specified folder with same structure?

Tags: bash, shell, bsd

I need a bash script like

headers ~/headers-folder ~/output-folder

so it recursively finds all .h files in ~/headers-folder and put them all in ~/output-folder with the folder hierarchy maintained?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

```
find /path/to/find -name "*.h" -type f | xargs -I {} cp --parents {} /path/to/destination
```

Check this out.

Comment: I was just about to post same string :)

Comment: Great snippet :) I was surprised to find that `xargs -I` handles paths with spaces too. I always used `find -print0`/`xargs -0` for that

Comment: cp: illegal option -- -

Comment: Also I need to maintain the folder structure in input folder.

Comment: @hzxu For maintaining the directory structure you need "--parents" option in "cp" command. Check whether you using the full version of cp or the one which come with busybox.

Comment: @ParthibanN Hi I'm using a Mac

Comment: @hzxu Am not familiar with BSD. Please add appropriate tag with your question.

Answer (score 2):

rsync is great for that too:

```
rsync --include '*.h' --filter 'hide,! */' -avm headers-folder/ output-folder/
```

This will copy all the `*.h` files, and create only the necessary directories.

---

Example:

```
mkdir -p headers-folder/{subdir,empty}
touch headers-folder/foo.h
touch headers-folder/subdir/foo.h

tree headers-folder

# headers-folder/
# |-- empty
# |-- foo.h
# `-- subdir
#     `-- foo.h

rsync --include '*.h' --filter 'hide,! */' -avm headers-folder/ output-folder/

tree output-folder

#  output-folder/
#  |-- foo.h
#  `-- subdir
#      `-- foo.h
```

Comment: This will output: output-folder/headers-folder/*, how can I change it so it copies header files with folder structures from headers-folder into output-folder without have another headers-folder inside output-folder?

Comment: I haven't found that to be true on my tests. Rsync version maybe? `rsync --version` gives "version 3.1.0  protocol version 31" to me.