# Bash shell / Command: strip out arbitrary components in a given path?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, bsd

Say if I have:

```
MYPATH=../Library/NetworkUtil/Classes/Headers/network.h
```

then I want to construct another path `AllHeaders/NetworkUtil/network.h`

I actually need to get different components out fro the original path, is there a way to do it?

I found in:

[Bash: remove first directory component from variable (path of file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311956/bash-remove-first-directory-component-from-variable-path-of-file)

I can something like

```
${MYPATH#../Library}
```

to strip out the specified part, but that assumes I know the structure already, what if in my case I need the 3rd and last components in the original path?

Thanks

Comment: Pretty similar questions from you one [after](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20415760/script-to-find-all-h-file-and-put-in-specified-folder-with-same-structure) the [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416524/unix-command-to-copy-all-h-file-with-modified-directory-structure).

Answer (score 0):

You can use bash arrays to access individual elements:

```
$ MYPATH=../Library/NetworkUtil/Classes/Headers/network.h
$ OLD="$IFS"
$ IFS='/' a=($MYPATH)
$ IFS="$OLD"
$ NEWPATH="AllHeaders/${a[2]}/${a[-1]}"
$ echo $NEWPATH
AllHeaders/NetworkUtil/network.h
```

ADDENDUM: For completeness, another way to make MYPATH into an array is to use bash's pattern substitution: `a=(${MYPATH//\// })`:

```
$ MYPATH=../Library/NetworkUtil/Classes/Headers/network.h
$ a=(${MYPATH//\// })
$ NEWPATH="AllHeaders/${a[2]}/${a[-1]}"
$ echo $NEWPATH
AllHeaders/NetworkUtil/network.h
```

This eliminates the need for messing with IFS but *would break badly* if MYPATH had spaces, tabs, or CR in it to begin with.

Comment: but I need ARBITRARY components, in my case I need the last one, which may not always be the 5th one, so a[5] does not work.

Comment: @hzxu,  No problem. The last element of an array is numbered "-1".  The answer is now updated.

Comment: A better way is to use `IFS=/ read -a a <<< "$MYPATH"`. It restricts the change to `IFS` to the `read` command, and it safely handles path components that contain whitespace.

Comment: Also a heads-up for people still using older versions of `bash`: you may need to use `${a[${#a[@]}-1]}` instead of `${a[-1]}`, as negative subscripts were introduced more recently.